# TableView Scroll Error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I am just learning to code on Xcode and currently in the process of learning how to use the TableView feature. I am trying to create 50 cells containing the numbers 1 to 50, but when I do a simulation on the iPhone 7, I can only scroll down to 15. The 15th cell is not a full cell either, and when I rotate my device horizontally I can only see 8 cells. Need help on this :(

This is the codes I'm using:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 50

    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = String(indexPath.row + 1)

        return cell

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

This is the screenshot at the bottom of the screen:
[Even cell 15 is not showing the full height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMA8G.png)

Comment: This sounds to me like the TableView control hasn't had constraints set to, say, fill the screen...   Can I suggest you add a screenshot of what you're seeing, particularly when you're at the bottom of the list.

Comment: what constraint you have on your UItableview in storyboard?

Comment: Potentially an issue with constraints, use 3D Hierarchy debug tool of XCode to see it, and you need to dequeue cells, use the reuse of cells.

Comment: I updated my question to have the screenshot at the bottom of the screen. The constraint I used is 0 spacing to the nearest neighbor. So in total I have 4 constraints, I did that by clicking the red lines at the "Add New Constraints" button on my mainstoryboard.

Comment: @Osca Yuwawira just give (leading ,trailing,top,bottom + width constraint )to your table.Or just delete this table view add one more with (leading ,trailing,top,bottom)

Answer (score 1):

change your code as below ::

```
 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

 var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
      if (cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
      }
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)."

        return cell

    }
```

Comment: Which parts do I need to replace with the code that you just gave me?
THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP BTW!

Comment: I'm still stuck at 15, and I don't know why. But Xcode won't let me run your code, it gave me several corrections like inserting brackets, adding "!", or adding "?".

Comment: Still not working. I feel like it has more to do with the constraints that I have set, or a problem with the setting of my simulator (although I haven't changed any settings to the simulator). So in total I have 4 constraints, I did that by clicking the red lines at the "Add New Constraints" button on my mainstoryboard and set the spacing to the nearest neighbor to 0

Comment: did you set leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints ?

Comment: Yes I did, I added leading, trailing, bottom space to: bottom layout, and top space to: Top Layout

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace:

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

By:

```
var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

And you should add in `viewDidLoad`:

```
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
```

Comment: I think I did the viewDidLoad thing at my main storyboard by control dragging my viewtable to the yellow dot thing twice, and checking the dataSource and delegate. When I changed the "let" to "var", Xcode gave me a comment that says "Variable 'cell' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant." Although I can ignore that comment and still run the code. Still won't let me scroll past 15 though. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to create 50 cells with a unique text? Can you scroll a little bit or is the tableView totally fixed?

Answer (score 0):

If you put your cell in storyboard then replace this code

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

to this,

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: This didn't work. I feel like it has more to do with the constraints that I have set, or a problem with the setting of my simulator (although I haven't changed any settings to the simulator). So in total I have 4 constraints, I did that by clicking the red lines at the "Add New Constraints" button on my mainstoryboard and set the spacing to the nearest neighbor to 0